# Setting the TableModel on an already constructed Table

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jtable, tablemodel

You can create a table model and add it to a table

```
TableModel tm = new TableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(tm);
```

however, if I init a Table

```
JTable table = new JTable();
```

and then create a table model later on...

```
TableModel tm = new TableModel();
tm.addValueAt(...);
...
```

Is there a way I can add this table model to the original table?

I've actually created my own classes to extend `TableModel` and `JTable`, and I thought that I could simply reconstruct the table given the new table model, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated here: [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29), You can use `setModel(TableModel)`

> **public void setModel(TableModel dataModel)**
>
> Sets the data model for
>   this table to newModel and registers with it for listener
>   notifications from the new data model.